# Symfony 2 w/ PhpUnit 3.6 : changing target hostname for test purposes

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I am testing a controller in that fashion :

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'lang/120');
```

Upon print_r'ing the $crawler object I can see that the target URL is http://localhost/lang/120. However, my target host is a virtual host set up on my machine, let's say http://www.somehost.tld and I'd like to use that. What clean means should I use for my unit tests to target that virtual host ?

I have tried putting a php variable in my phpunit.xml.dist file and use it :

```
<php>
    <server name="HOSTNAME" value="http://www.somehost.tld/app.php/" />
</php>
```

And then :

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $_SERVER['HOSTNAME'] . 'lang/120');
```

But that looks awkward...Is there any config file (the config_test file ?) where I should put that virtual hostname ?

Thanks for helping, everyone !

Answer (score 17):

You can also pass HTTP_HOST in server parameters to change the target host name:

```
self::createClient(array(), array(
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'sample.host.com',
));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could set those values as DIC (Dependency Injection Container) parameters in `config/config_test.yml`.

Basically just add them like this:

```
parameters:
    myapp.test.hostname.somehost: http://www.somehost.tld
    myapp.test.hostname.otherhost: https://www.otherhost.tld
```

Then you can create a helper method on your test class to get the url for a certain host:

```
private function getHostUrl($hostId, $path = '')
{
    return self::$kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('myapp.test.hostname.'.$hostId).$path;
}
```

Note: I'll assume that you are using the `WebTestCase`.

Finally, make use of this in your test:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $this->getHostUrl('somehost', '/lang/120'));
```

Comment: That sounds fine, Igor, thanks ! However, this would trigger a Accessing static property \..\..\LanguageControllerTest::$kernel as non static...which is resolved by using "self::$kernel->..."

Comment: My bad, looks like this was changed at some point. It must indeed now be self::$kernel. Fixing my answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to igorw, if you have your hostname as parameter in a config file, like :

```
#config/config_test.yml
parameters:
    myapp_hostname: "http://www.myapp.com"
```

In your WebTestCase, you can get the hostname from parameters, and set the HTTP_HOST parameter to client :

```
$client = self::createClient();
$hostname = $client->getContainer()->getParameter('myapp_hostname');
$client->setServerParameter('HTTP_HOST', $hostname );
$client->request('GET', '/lang/120');
```

In your code to test, the Request object contains the hostname :

```
'http://www.myapp.com/lang/120' === $request->getUri();
```